# For mySQL how can I do 6 selects and 2 left joins at once?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning SQL and wanted to combine 3 tables, with 6 outputs (2 per table) through the id and userid.  This all looks correct but gives me this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'guestbook.id' in 'on clause'.

```
SELECT yacka.userid, yacka.yackmane, registered.id, registered.Name, guestbook.id, guestbook.name FROM yacka 
LEFT JOIN registered on yacka.userid = guestbook.id 
LEFT JOIN guestbook on yacka.userid = guestbook.id;
```

Comment: You can't refer to a column before the table appears in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LEFT JOIN registered** should have an **ON** Condition with **registered** table,  but you are using **guestbook** table which is still not declared, changing the query to below once will not throw exception

```
SELECT yacka.userid, yacka.yackmane, registered.id, 
       registered.Name,guestbook.id, guestbook.name FROM yacka 
LEFT JOIN registered on yacka.userid = registered.id 
LEFT JOIN guestbook on yacka.userid = guestbook.id;
```